# SQL Server - get parameters of executed stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

In my system, I have very large stored procedures in SQL Server which are called by a 3rd party company which is sending data this way.

I'm trying to solve an issue where the data is not processed correctly and I would like to have a log of commands sent to SQL Server.

For example, the client executes:

```
EXEC sp_our_procedure @param1, @param2, etc.
```

Is there any way to get text of command inside of stored procedure? I would like to save this text "EXEC ..." to database?

Comment: Take a look at the SQL Server Profiler tool or SQL Trace in MSDN.

Comment: when 3rd party user call `EXEC sp_our_procedure @param1, @param2, etc` this SP your can write a code to insert client `SQL` in some another table